# Change the rule name of executable Cmake

Tags: cmake, makefile

I would like to change the name of the rule in the makefile generated by cmake. Currently, the rule is named like the executable itself. How do I change to a custom name?

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project(jetpack2tek3 C)

include_directories(inc)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11 )

add_executable(serverJ2T3
        src/socket_server.c
        src/socket.c
        src/socket_commands.c
        src/commands/id.c
        src/commands/map.c
        src/commands/ready.c
        src/commands/fire.c
        src/commands/start.c
        src/commands/player.c
        src/commands/coin.c
        src/commands/finish.c
```

My makefile generated:

```
# Build rule for target.
serverJ2T3: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) $(MAKESILENT) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 serverJ2T3
.PHONY : serverJ2T3
```

Expected output:

```
# Build rule for target.
server: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) $(MAKESILENT) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 serverJ2T3
.PHONY : serverJ2T3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
add_executable(server ...)
set_target_properties(server PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME serverJ2T3)
```

That gives you a make target named `server` but with `serverJ2T3` as the executable filename.

Ref: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/OUTPUT_NAME.html

Comment: set_target_properties called with illegal arguments, maybe missing a
  PROPERTIES specifier?

Comment: @dolor3sh4ze Yes, fixed.  Does it work for you?

Comment: of course, thanks